# Monads not useful in strict languages?

Tags: scala, monads

So Steven F. Lott in his book "Functional Python Programming" (start of chapter 13) writes:

> A monad allows us to impose an order on an expression evaluation in an otherwise lenient language. We can use a monad to insist that an expression such as `a + b + c` is evaluated in left-to-right order. This can interfere with the compiler’s ability to optimize expression evaluation. This is necessary, however, when we want files to have their content read or written in a specific order: a monad is a way to assure that the `read()` and `write()` functions are evaluated in a particular order.
>
> Languages that are lenient and have optimizing compilers benefit from monads imposing order on the evaluation of expressions. Python, for the most part, is strict and does not optimize, meaning there are few practical requirements for monads in Python.

Personally, I don't know much about monads. But in Scala, monads, ... I found them more used as a sort of alternative to control structures, sometimes dramatically simplifying the code.

E. g. the `Either` monad can be used to propagate an unhappy or finished scenario that does not need any further processing, by using a series of `flatMap`s.

So could someone explain to me what Steven F. Lott is up to here? What does it mean that monads aren't "practically required" in strict languages?

A **concrete** example in Scala (sadly, don't know any Haskell) would be interesting that shows: When using Scala's lazy features you must use monads, while when remaining strict, they're optional.

Comment: "Strict" here is very close to "eager evaluation". If you have eager evaluation then you might have a problem achieving "referential transparency" (fancy word which could be better sold as "stress-free refactoring whether side-effects are there or not"). But you are certain that side effects will be triggered in the order they appear in the code. In Scala when you use an IO monad (like Cats' Effect IO, ZIO, earlier Scalaz or Monix Task) you have a code which is lazily evaluated and non-memoized, which helps achieving RT. It helps making you code easy to read and refactor, but require extra DSL

Comment: (next comment since there was a character limit). Of course, this code is easy to read as long as you get used to the convention, like with any other convention. As long as the convention is unfamiliar it won't look that way. I wouldn't get much deeper here since... this topic was tired ad nauseam on every Scala conference for the last 10 years. Just search for Scala and IO monad on Stack Overflow, Reddit, Google in general. Or get the "Functional Programmin in Scala" which even describes how to implement a simple IO monad yourself.